# Jquery Retrieve cell value based on state of another cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors, cells

I need some help with selecting a cell in my gridview. I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>CheckBox</th>
<th>Customer ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CheckBox</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>Joe</td>
<td>Blogs</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CheckBox</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Chris</td>
<td>White</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to select the ID cell of the row that is currently checked. How would you do this?

I have had a search but cant seem to find anything like the above.

Comment: Your `tr` elements don't have `id` attributes. Post the real mark-up, please.

Comment: @David Thomas - I believe the 'id cell' is the second column of each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
   if(this.checked){
       var id =  $(this).parent().next().text();       
       // assuming your second column has id you're looking for [customer id]
   }
});
```

[`wokring demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/uNC6m/)

Answer (score 2):

In theory, this would work:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           var theRowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        }
    });
```

[A quick and dirty JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gebp5/).

---

**Edited:** to atone for my misunderstanding the question, and the html:

Given that the number you want to find is stored within a cell  (a cell to which I've assigned a class 'rowID', for ease of access) the following works:

```
$(document).ready(

function() {
    $('.rowID').each(
        function(i){
            $(this).text(i+1);
        });
    $('input:checkbox').change(

    function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var theRowId = $(this).parent().siblings('.rowID').text();
            $('#rowId').text(theRowId);
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gebp5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your base structure is:

```
<tr>
<td>CheckBox</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Chris</td>
<td>White</td>
</tr>
```

So this may solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('tr td').find('checkbox').click(function()
    {
        var line_id = $(this).parent('td').next().text();
    });
});
```

I hope it helps! ^^